# How to track jos-Error in Joomla 2.5?

Tags: php, error-handling, joomla2.5

I made one of my menu items only for Guests (not logged in users). ANd If user logs in, it disappears from menu. It works fine...

But I noticed that when I put the link to the Guest menu item in browser, when I'm lnot ogged in , it shows very disgusting **jos-Error: You are not authorised to view this resource**.

I want to find a way to track such errors and redirect to custom 404 page or some other page.

Please, assist me in this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string **You are not authorised to view this resource** located in `JERROR_ALERTNOAUTHOR` language string and fire in `includes/application.php` function:

```
public function authorise($itemid)
    {
        $menus  = $this->getMenu();
        $user   = JFactory::getUser();

        if (!$menus->authorise($itemid))
        {
            if ($user->get('id') == 0)
            {
                // Redirect to login
                $uri        = JFactory::getURI();
                $return     = (string)$uri;

                $this->setUserState('users.login.form.data', array( 'return' => $return ) );

                $url    = 'index.php?option=com_users&view=login';
                $url    = JRoute::_($url, false);

                $this->redirect($url, JText::_('JGLOBAL_YOU_MUST_LOGIN_FIRST'));
            }
            else {
                JError::raiseError(403, JText::_('JERROR_ALERTNOAUTHOR'));
            }
        }
    }
```

You could alter this function and add redirection or change the text string with your desired message.

Redirect could be done with [redirect()](http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JApplication.html#method_redirect) method.

An example of redirect syntax:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->redirect(JRoute::_(JURI::root().'index.php'));
```

Please make sure that you won't alter `application.php` without creating an [override system plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core).

Hope this helps

Comment: Works as a charm! Thanks